# Send Notification (Toast) every friday at specific time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have used [How to implement background agents for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx) to send local toast notification in my wp8 app. However I am not sure is it possible to send toast notifications at specific day and time say (Every friday at specific time)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is the [ScheduledToastNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification.aspx) in Win-RT. You will have to reschedule it from time to time though.